# Transforming a Curl command in Jmeter for generating authentication token

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, jmeter

I have the below command i use to run in terminal to get the Authorization token

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic SXN4dWNmXYZlelJCTnVyui5NcUNpoVcxWnhRYTo1UGI5M2I0aDlIWFZUdnJiNldPolFnNWQ5ckFh"
```

https://xxxxxx:8080/token

I want to transform this to jmeter and automate it so that i dont have to run the command manually every time but the jmeter runs for me and stores in a variable to be used for next tests

any idea of how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Curl]
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]

---

Also be aware that you can easily convert your `curl` command into a JMeter HTTP Request by just recording it.

- From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create`
- Click `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder -> Start`
- Execute your `curl` command and add `-x http://localhost:8888` parameter to it like:

  ```
  curl -x http://localhost:8888 -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic SXN4dWNmXYZlelJCTnVyui5NcUNpoVcxWnhRYTo1UGI5M2I0aDlIWFZUdnJiNldPolFnNWQ5ckFh" http://xxxxxx.com/token
  ```
- That's it, JMeter will capture the request and store it under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

See [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) article for more details on the approach.

Comment: Perfect , Thanks a lot Works like a charm.I received the token in Response data tab . Now am trying to figure out with Bean shell pre processor in order to extract the token alone from the response and store in a variable . Do you have some pointers in extracting the value to variable ?

Comment: You need a [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), not pre-processor. The exact choice depends on response data type (XPath Extractor for XML/XHTML/HTML, CSS/JQuery Extractor for HTML, JSON Extractor for JSON, Regular Expression Extractor for anything else). The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)